# White screen after plugins upgrade

Tags: plugins

For some reason when I upgraded all the plugins, I got a white screen. Is there any way to debug it?

Comment: This might be issue with htaccess. Try renaming it to something other and then visit your website. Its a common problem in wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to FTP using FileZilla. Rename each plugin folder name one by one and see which plugin is causing the issue.

Once you found out the plugin which is causing the problem. Just reinstall it.

Comment: Whats the point in renaming the folders name before even checking errors in htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on debugging in WordPress. Add the following lines in your wp-config.php file. After that check the debug.log file in the wp-content directory.

```
// Turns WordPress debugging on
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Tells WordPress to log everything to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

// Doesn't force the PHP 'display_errors' variable to be on
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

// Hides errors from being displayed on-screen
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```